# How to close the modal dialog: SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose in Add-In

Tags: sharepoint-online, wcf

**Current Environment: SharePoint online 2013**

Could someone suggest on how to close the SharePoint Add-In modal dialog.

I have created a custom action on a library using a `wcf service`. When clicked on the custom action link with in the library I am displaying a modal dialog which has a custom hosted add-in page.

Upon some user selection & save button click I would like to close this modal dialog & open up a new word document based on a template.

The problem is I get access denied & assuming that the call back function is in a different page & hence access denied??

Here is the full code below. If I move the `CoreInvoke` statement which opens the doc, in to the client js "onFileCreated" function, I am able to open the document as desired, how ever I am not able to close the modal dialog as I was able to do in SP2010 application, because access being denied.

Here is the complete code:

Step 1: CSOM - Adding Custom action to the library using WCF service

```
UserCustomAction action = libraryList.UserCustomActions.Add(); action.Title = ActionTitle; action.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon"; action.Sequence = 403; action.CommandUIExtension = GetCommandXml(); action.Update(); context.ExecuteQuery();




private string GetCommandXml()
        {
            string dialogUrl = "https://mysharepoint.com/TemplateRibbonActionAddIn/Pages/Templates.aspx";
            dialogUrl += "?SPListId=" + _currentListId
                         + "&amp;TemplateSiteUrl=" + _templateLibrarySiteColUrl
                         + "&amp;SPHostUrl=" + _hostWebUrl
                         + "&amp;TemplateWebUrl=" + _templateLibraryWebUrl
                         + "&amp;TemplateLibraryTitle=" + Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(_templateLibraryTitle, true);
        string commandAction =
            "javascript: " +
            "function templateCallback(result, returnValue) { if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) { CoreInvoke('createNewDocumentWithProgIDEx', event, returnValue.templateUrl, returnValue.saveUrl, 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', false); } } " +
            "var dialogUrl = '" + dialogUrl +"' ; " +
            "var options = {url: dialogUrl, title: 'Select Template', dialogReturnValueCallback: templateCallback, height: 800, width: 600}; " +
            "SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);";

        string xml =
        "<CommandUIExtension>" +
            "<CommandUIDefinitions>" +
                "<CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children\">" +
                    "<Button Id=\"" + ActionButtonId + "\" " +
                        "Alt=\"New From Template\" " +
                        "Sequence=\"40\" " +
                        "Command=\"{C8119B79-DC95-4587-94F6-3767D549AF49}\" " +
                        "Image32by32=\"/_layouts/15/images/lg_icdotx.png\" " +
                        "Image16by16=\"/_layouts/15/images/icdotx.gif\" " +
                        "LabelText=\"Select Template\" " +
                        "TemplateAlias=\"o1\" />" +
                "</CommandUIDefinition>" +
            "</CommandUIDefinitions>" +

            "<CommandUIHandlers>" +
                "<CommandUIHandler " +
                "Command=\"{C8119B79-DC95-4587-94F6-3767D549AF49}\" " +
                "CommandAction=\"" + commandAction  + "\" />" +
            "</CommandUIHandlers>" +
        "</CommandUIExtension>";
        return xml;
    }
```

With in the Hosted add in page, below function triggers on save button click

```
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadTemplates, "sp.js");
        $('.btnSave').click(function () {
            try {


            var selectedContentType = $('.ddlContentTypes').val();
            var selectedTemplate = $('.txtSelectedTemplate').val();
            if (selectedContentType == null || selectedContentType == '' || selectedTemplate == null || selectedTemplate == '') {
                 alert("Please make sure to select a template & content type before you click save.")
            } else {
                intialise();
                context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

                var svcUrl = 

    "http://amigosito365.azurewebsites.net/MyHybridService.svc/CreateDocumentWithTemplateOptions/?SPHostWebUrl="
    + encodeURIComponent(hostWebUrl) + "&SPListId=" + spListId + "&TemplateSiteUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(templateSiteUrl) + "&LibraryTitle=" + encodeURIComponent(templateLibraryTitle) +"&" + selectedTemplate + "&ContentType=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedContentType);
                    var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();

                    request.set_url(

                         svcUrl

                         );

                    request.set_method("GET");

                    request.set_headers({ "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" });


                    response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);

                    context.executeQueryAsync(onFileCreated, onQueryFailed);

                }



            } 


***********************************************************************

function onFileCreated(data,status,jqXHR) {
    var jsonData = data.$1L_0[1].$G_1;
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    if (data.Success) {
        if (data.TemplateFullUrl != "" && data.FileSaveUrl != "") {

            try {

                    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

                    var args = {
                        templateUrl: data.TemplateFullUrl,
                        saveUrl: data.FileSaveUrl

                    };


                }, "SP.UI.Dialog.js");
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.message + " Stack: " + e.stack);

            }

        }

    } else {
        alert("Error occurred while creating the template file.")
    } }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed fix the above issue as suggested in the [post](http://tricky-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/close-modal-dialog-from-app-page-in.html) by **Alex Terentiev**:

Here is my updated fileCreated function, I had to comment the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () )` and call the `coreinvoke` to open the document as required and post the message to parent to close dialog.

```
 if (data.TemplateFullUrl != "" && data.FileSaveUrl != "") {

        try {

                //ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

               // var args = {
                //    templateUrl: data.TemplateFullUrl,
                //    saveUrl: data.FileSaveUrl

               // };


            //}, "SP.UI.Dialog.js");
CoreInvoke('createNewDocumentWithProgIDEx', event, data.TemplateFullUrl, data.FileSaveUrl, 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', false);

 // posting a message
 var target = parent.postMessage ? parent : 
(parent.document.postMessage ? parent.document : undefined); 
 if (target) 
target.postMessage('CloseDialog', '*');

        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message + " Stack: " + e.stack);

        }
```

Thanks.